# Backbutton to return to previous layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ok, say I have 1 Activity called MainActivity and 2 layouts linked to this actvity. In layout 1 i have a button which when clicked opens a webview in layout 2. How can I make it so when i press backbutton it goes back to layout 1 and doesnt exit the whole app.

Edit: fixed this by just creating another class and linking it to one of the layouts.

Comment: i think the better choice would be create two activities and keep your webview inside second activity.also some code would be much more helpful

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `onBackPressed()` in your activity and handle the logic there.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(/*layout2 visible*/){
     // code here to go back to layout 1
    }else{
          super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(R.layout.webview visible){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new doit().execute();}
        else{super.onBackPressed();}
 }

I get error: cannot resolve symbol visible

Comment: It's a comment/an example, you have to provide a proper condition

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to programming. I'll try to figure it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code using onBackPressed()

1- activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/go_to_second_layout"
            android:text="Go to second layout"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

2- second_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/second_layout">
```

3- MainActivity.java

```
    public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId){
    case R.id.go_to_second_layout:{
     setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_layout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    break;}}}
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_layout)).VISIBLE==View.VISIBLE){
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_layout)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
            super.onBackPressed();}
        }
```